# CSS positing on on other div

Tags: html, css

I have a question - I need to make the 1st layer be a header, the 2nd layer as navigation and the 3rd layer as a photo. Also I need to make, that 2nd will be on the 3rd layer, but not in the third.

All these three layers must be at different elements.

Thanks for the answers.

Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lbahohfz/

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <header>Some content</header>
    <nav>Some content</nav>
    <img src="http://b-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css-      style-300x1541.png"/> <!--this layer must be shown under nav (cyan background)--  >
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0px;
}
header{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: midlle;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
nav{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: midlle;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    background: cyan;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
img {
 height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you put a snapshot to show what you are looking for?

Comment: Check your spelling of "middle".  You have "midlle".

Comment: can you post a snapshot of what u r looking for??

Comment: I just wrote this code for an example. Here is what i need to code http://www.part.lt/perziura/e16dcd32cd4d861fc4958b24b67d09bb57.PNG

Answer (score 2):

Just add these css attributes to the `img` tag:

```
img {
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbahohfz/1/)